# Typesafe way to provide enriched dependencies to derived classes in C++

Tags: c++, dependency-injection, type-safety

My title is probably not great -- I'm open to suggestions.

Right now I have library code that provides base functionality for a class that has some dependencies. The code looks something like this:

```
class Fan { /* ... */ };
class PanametricFan : public Fan { /* ... */ };
class DeskFan : public Fan { /* ... */ };

class LogCasing { /* ... */ };
class MalleableLogCasing : public LogCasing { /* ... */ };

struct EncabulatorDependencies
{
  Fan * fan;
  LogCasing * casing;
};

EncabulatorDependencies setupDependencies
  (const std::string & confFile) { /* ... */ }

class Encabulator
{
  public:
    Encabulator(const EncabulatorDependencies & dependencies);

  // ...
};
```

Now in user code, I have something like this:

```
class TurboEncabulator : public Encabulator { /* ... */ }
```

Now while the base class functionality in **Encabulator** can do just fine with any sort of **Fan** and **LogCasing**, the **TurboEncabulator** specifically needs a **Panametric Fan** and a **MalleableLogCasing** to work.

Of course if the config file was set up properly, then `setupDependencies` will give me the right kind of fan and casing, which I could just cast them, like so:

```
TurboEncabulator::TurboEncabulator(const EncabulatorDependencies & deps)
: Encabulator(deps)
{
  myPanametricFan = dynamic_cast<PanametricFan *>(deps.fan);
  myMalleableCasing = dynamic_cast<MalleableLogCasing *>(deps.casing);

  //..
}
```

But I'd like to do something a little more typesafe.

My idea was to replace EncabulatorDependencies with a list of variants and have something that says, say, "give me a `Fan *` from this collection" (including, say, a pointer to any derived class of `Fan`), or "give me a `PanametricFan *` from this collection."  Something like

```
Encabulator::Encabulator(const EncabulatorDependencies & deps)
{
  myFan = deps.get<Fan *>();
  myCasing = deps.get<LogCasing *>();
}
```

in the library and

```
TurboEncabulator::TurboEncabulator(const EncabulatorDependencies & deps)
{
  myPanametricFan = deps.get<PanametricFan *>();
  myMalleableCasing = deps.get<MalleableLogCasing *>();
}
```

in the user code.

Then the `setupDependencies` method can just build the appropriate derived-type object and throw a pointer into the dependency list, the `Encabulator` can have its `Fan *`, the `TurboEncabulator` can have is `PanametricFan *`, and if the config file isn't set up properly the system can produce a sane error message.

Of course I can think of a couple of "dirty" ways this could be accomplished -- `EncabulatorDependencies` could just hold separate `Fan *`, `Panametric Fan *`, `Desk Fan *`, etc. pointers and client code could grab the one it wants, for instance -- but I was hoping there was a "right" way to do this that doesn't incur extra maintenance costs.

Comment: @TedLyngmo The type of the object constructed by `setupDependencies` will depend on what's in the conf file.

Comment: Ah... removing comment

Comment: @MaxLanghof: Fixed, thanks.

Comment: How would `setupDependencies` know whether a `PanametricFan` is needed?

Comment: @DavisHerring: The config file would tell it what kind of fan to make.  If it turns out to be an inappropriate type for the particular encabulator then the encabulator will have a runtime error during setup.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I was able to solve this problem as follows:

First, I need a base `Tool` class that all the classes inherit from, and this class needs to have runtime type information (RTTI).  The easiest way to do this is to give it a virtual method, since this essentially forces it to have a vtable.  And since anything that has virtual methods needs a virtual destructor anyway, it's okay to make this class nothing *but* a virtual destructor:

```
class Tool
{
  public:

    virtual ~Tool() = default;
};
```

Next, I just need something that holds all my tools:

```
std::vector<Tool *> myTools;
```

Now when I want a tool, all I have to do is iterate through the vector and attempt to convert things to my type until I find one that will convert successfully:

```
template<class T> T& grabTool()
{
  static_assert<std::is_base_of_v<Tool, T>);

  for(Tool * t : myTools)
  {
    try
    {
      return dynamic_cast<T&>(*t);
    }
    catch(const std::bad_cast &) { }
  }

  throw std::out_of_range(typeid(T).name());
}
```

Note that we need to work with references instead of working directly with pointers here, since `dynamic_cast` will happily a base pointer to a derived pointer without checking what it's actually pointing at.